# CSS Box model width problem

Tags: css

I am newbiew to css.
Please have a look of this simple two column layout first.

http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/2-col-css.html

I want to ask why the width of content + width of sidebar =/= width of container?

Comment: Could you link to/attach the layout?

Comment: You should paste your code here, and if possible prepare a test case of the problem at www.jsfiddle.net. Also @ahadley we encourage users to paste their code here, and not elsewhere and link here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Rikudo. Still finding my way around!

Comment: I agree with @Rikudo, pasting your code would be best.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to post the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Width of content = 610px

Width of padding in content = 5+5 = 10px

Total width of content = 620px

Similarly Total width of sidebar with padding = 340px

So total content and sidebar = 620+340 = 960px which is equal to width of container !

Answer (score 2):

The W3C specification says that the width of a box is: margin + border + padding + width. In this way you'll be able to determine the actual box width.

If you sum the resulting box widths you will have a result equal to the container width.

Comment: Don't you mean just 'equal to'? It won't be less than.

Comment: Yes, equal to, in the context of the question.

Comment: So you should remove "less or" from your answer for it to be correct.

Comment: I tried to give a general answer with regard to the W3C standard.

Comment: It's always equal to. Never less than. Less than is wrong. -1 for not fixing your answer.

Comment: No problem. But if you have two 350px boxes and the container is 701px, the sum of your boxes is less than 701px but the layout won't be destroyed. And, as you can see, the answer was "fixed" a while back.

Comment: Egads... I am sooo sorry.. I missed the edit! I just did a trivial edit so I could remove my -1 vote.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it's hard to give you an answer. But some basic CSS and html is below which will give you a content area the same size as your header, see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/peter/wZQNY/

The CSS

```
.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
}
.header{
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
}
.content{
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header navigation</div>
    <div class="content">page content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the problem. In your link, the content.width + sidebar.width == container.width

What's your problem? what browser are you using?

---

A possible solution is that you may have some weird behavior due to border or margins, for that, you should apply a **[CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**.